# Sqoop import all tables into hive gets stuck with below statement

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

By by default tables are moving to HDFS not to warehouse directory(user/hive/warehouse)

```
sqoop import-all-tables \
  --num-mappers 1 \
  --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
  --username=retail_dba \
  --password=cloudera \
  --hive-import \
  --hive-overwrite \
  --create-hive-table \
  --compress \
  --compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec \
  --outdir java_files
```

Tried with `--hive-home` by overriding $HIVE_HOME- No use

Can any one suggest me the reason?

Comment: try running with --verbose and post logs to get more help

Comment: @vgunnu - Attached the logs in the location
http://pastebin.com/hHTJSLCk
In logs i observe, By default the import tables are not moving to warehouse they are getting imported to "/user/cloudera"

I have total of 6 tables in mysql when i perform import-all-tables it is by default importing first table categories alone....

Comment: @RAJASHYAM - sqoop imports to /user/cloudera first at temporary location and then move data to Hive location (if import to temporary location was successful). As per you comment that in logs you are seeing only one table imported instead of 6, it tells me that import process have had aborted some where at in process of importing first table itself. - first delete/rename all the dirs on /user/cloudera location that matches any table name to be imported from MySQL than try sqoop command again.

Comment: If are not seeing tables in warehouse, your target database might have been created using another default location. Create database or use the database you know defaults to your warehouse. Use --hive-database to set the database and try. more info can be found. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-912

Comment: @vgunnu- I tried with specifying the _--hive-database_ in sqoop_import and the database exists in hive warehouse. Attaching the trace for more details
[Sqoop_import_hive database logs](http://pastebin.com/qLbQBt14)