# How to get the default HIVE_HOME in cloudera quickstartVM -5.7.0?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

How can i get value for environment variable **$HIVE_HOME** in cloudera-quickstartVM-5.7?

Tried to see the existing environment variables by *printenv*, It does not exist.

Comment: `sudo echo $HIVE_HOME` - it's usually `/usr/lib/hive` on cloudera

Comment: when i tired with {sudo echo **$HIVE_HOME**} its printing empty..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`HIVE_HOME` is set when `hive` shell is invoked. here are three ways to find out `HIVE_HOME`

From `hive`commandline:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hive -e '!env'|grep HIVE_HOME
HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive
```

From `hive` shell - this will print same variables as above 
but you can't use grep here, so you will have to find `HIVE_HOME` from list of all variables:

```
hive> !env;
```

From `hive` command file itself:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ cat /usr/bin/hive|grep HIVE_HOME
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive
```

Comment: Thanks @BigDataLearner. When i import tables via **sqoop-import-all** into hive.by default as per the document it should go to my warehouse directory(*/user/hive/warehouse*)..But table is getting moved to default HDFS directory(*/user/cloudera*).Can u suggest me the solution?

Comment: If this answers your question than please accept this as answer and open up new question thread as `sqoop import` is diff topic. (Hint: run `sqoop` command with `--warehouse-dir ` and/or `--hive-home` options) -also share your sqoop command...

Comment: Ok..Thank you.

The link to the question on sqoop is [sqoop-import to hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135520/sqoop-import-all-tables-into-hive-gets-stuck-with-below-statement)